# Unable to Build Spring Boot Project with Flyway and Test Class

Tags: flyway

I have added flyway to our spring boot java application.  The only way I can successfully build the project with maven is to comment out
the test class.  Otherwise I receive a flyway error when flyway encounters a SQL script that is attempting to create indexes within a 
Create Table script.  The errors are below:
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException:
Message    : Unknown data type: "IDK_COMPANIES_CITY"; SQL statement:
How can I get my project to build without commenting out the tests?  The test class is below: Note:  I can comment out the Test class, build and deploy the project successfully.  All the SQL scripts migrate successfully.  The application is using a MariaDB in the cloud.  Thanks.

```
package com.spring.sample;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DatabaseTestApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class DatabaseTestApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using an in-memory database in your tests, rather than connecting to a live one. That could mean that the in-memory database that is being created when your tests are run does not support the syntax inside your Flyway-scripts.

Try setting this in your test application properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

The reason I suggest using MySQLDialect is that there is none for MariaDB and because it says so in [MariaDB's Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/hibernate-mariadb/).

If the above doesn't work, try this property instead:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```